# Vertical aligment not working properly

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/1/

I want the text to be placed at the 50% of the image height - so just in the middle of the box.

I was searching a lot on SO and google - there are a lot of questions like this, but each other is about another problem... I was tried the solutions given by people but none of them worked so thats why I'm asking you here for any solution!

Comment: A good primer: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace the following with these:

```
#column-content {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
}

img{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

it's the image you want to center.

Comment: Oh... I missed very little to achieve what I wanted `:p`.

Answer (score 4):

Just set `vertical-align: middle` on the `img`.

http://jsfiddle.net/9Y7Cm/2/